# Xamarin with hover over event

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mouseover, xamarin.uwp

I’m converting a Winform application into a Xamarin form for Android and UWP.

I’m trying to find a way to replicate a WinForm mouse over event, but can’t seem to find an event or away around this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Forms don't support on hover event.

If you want to add the on hover event for a particular platform and particular control you need to create a custom renderer for it. On some platforms (like iOS) there is no such thing as on hover.

This is an example of it (though it uses effect and not custom renderer but those are similar approach and both may be valid for your case): https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/147498/how-can-i-change-an-image-border-color-on-hover-in-xamarin

Comment: Ah thanks thought it was not supported,l directly. Will look at custom render and we where I go. Thanks for pointing me down a path